# How to protect "master" branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

We are a team of a few people. Everyone works on a feature branch and merges his stuff through GitHub UI into `master` when one is ready.

Now is it possible to prevent direct pushes to `master`, but instead create a `pull request` whenever a new feature is ready to be merged? Additionally it would be awsome to restrict merges to a subset of devs only.

Comment: The best way is to have a clear workflow.

Comment: Look into [roles](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/) in GitHub. Developers with read access can work on branches in their foked repositories and create PR's when their feature branch is ready to be merged.

Comment: GitHub has a feature called [protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches). It won't take you all the way – for example it doesn't prevent anyone from committing directly to `master` – but at least it's a good start.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio That unfortunately does not solve the problem, since its only for forced push.

Comment: @HBHB We have a private repo so one premium account. If one of my colleges clone the repo, it will be public, right?

Comment: @Aley no. If the repository is private your colleagues can fork it and their forked repositories will stay private. You just need to give them the rights to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Additionally it would be awsome to restrict merges to a subset of devs only.

You can [restrict pushes to a branch](https://help.github.com/enterprise/user/articles/enabling-branch-restrictions/) in an Organization to specific users or teams. This will allow you to set up a team that can merge back into `master`.

[image: branch restriction gif]

Alternatively, for a small team, you can consider having each developer set up client-side hooks to prevent pushing to a remote `master`.

Lastly, if you use GitHub Enterprise that offers pre-receive hooks, you can enable one that [enforces code to be merged through a PR](https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/restrict-master-to-gui-merges.sh)

Answer (score 0):

go to settings tab click on Branches --> select Branch Protection Rules and here click Add Rules button, Branch name patterns = `master`

then tick below checkboxes

1. Require pull request review before merging
2. Require review from CODEOWNER file.

**Note:** -Add CODEOWNER file in your git top folder and inside it maintain Lead developers who can approve name like this `* @apple @orange`

You can read more on codeowner in below link https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners

We haven't ticked include administrator option, Admin role account can do merge without review.